# MFMailComposeViewController View flickering issue

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When i display the MFMailComposeViewController it view flicker (first goes inside Navigation bar and then come down to correct position) first seems like "To" field goes inside navigation bar and then come out. I am using the following code.`
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        self.mailPicker = MFMailComposeViewController()

```
    self.mailPicker!.setToRecipients(self.mailer)
    self.mailPicker!.setSubject("hello");
    self.mailPicker!.setMessageBody("message text", isHTML: false);
    self.mailPicker!.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    self.mailPicker!.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(self.mailPicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this to your viewcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = YES;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```